# How to iterate over objects stored in a JavaScript array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

I'm coding a simple JavaScript currency converter. Pulled the currency data from an API and stored it to a state object. Next, I wanted to add currency name, country and symbol to the app so I'm pulling that data from a Rest Countries API and storing it to "currencies" array.

Here's the code:

```
export const state = {
  date: [],
  time: {},
  currency: [],
  rates: {},
  result: [],
};

export const getSymbolsCountry = async function (symbol) {
  try {
    const data = await fetch(`https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/currency/${symbol}`);
    const json = await data.json();
    addInfoToSymbol(json[0]);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
};

function addInfoToSymbol(data) {
  let country = {
    code: data.currencies[0].code,
    symbol: data.currencies[0].symbol,
    flag: data.flag,
    country: data.name,
  };

  state.currency.push(country);
}
```

Console logging the currency from state shows that it's an array but using map or forEach on it does nothing.
[console log state.currency](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b9Wou.png)
Could someone please help me understand what I'm doing wrong cause I can't wrap my head around it.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by *using map of forEach on it does nothing* ?

Here is an example where I use `forEach` on `state.currency` and its working perfectly.

```js
const state = {
  currency: []
};

const getSymbolsCountry = async function (symbol) {
  try {
    const data = await fetch(`https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/currency/${symbol}`);
    const json = await data.json();
    addInfoToSymbol(json[0]);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
};

function addInfoToSymbol(data) {
  let country = {
    code: data.currencies[0].code,
    symbol: data.currencies[0].symbol,
    flag: data.flag,
    country: data.name,
  };

  state.currency.push(country);
}

Promise.all([
  getSymbolsCountry("EUR"),
  getSymbolsCountry("USD"),
  getSymbolsCountry("JPY")
])
.then(() =>
  state.currency.forEach(({code}) => 
    $("#result").append("<li>" + code + "</li>")
  )
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="result"></ul>
```

Comment: Well, I'm passing state.curency crom the controller to the view class and it's show method and i don't get anything in the console log:
show(val) {
    val.forEach(cur => console.log(cur));
  }